# Storing user infos in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 project and I'm using JWT. But, I couldn't decide where can I store user infos(A lot of info). If I use  JWT, then JWT will be very big. I think there is 4 possibility for this. But which one is better and recommended for doing this?

**1) Local Storage (in browser)**

**2) SessionStorage (in browser)**

**3) JWT**

**4) Variable** (I think this is bad because if I refresh page then will disappear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either in local storage / indexDb or in jwt token

1) if you do it in your JWT token then you will have to decode the token every time you wanna use user info(Less preferable).

```
pro -> user info will be encrypted into the token
```

2)If you store it in local storage or indexDb then you can directly use it by getting value from it which is fast and easy(prefrable).

> con ->user info will be exposed via local storage or indexDb

if You are fine with exposing user then I will recommend you to use the second approach.

Comment: Thanks. But, even if I use JWT, every people can easily get jwt and decode from "jwt.io" website.

Comment: Yes, still it will not be directly exposed. and moreover you won't have to decode every time you need user info

Answer (score 1):

You can use all, but  Local Storage  for preferences of ui in screen, SessionStorage of system preferences if you not write in DB server. JWT is more appropriate for sensitive data like as person for transmite to your serve and variable is for parse data less sensitive to pages.
You must see your business first for to take your decision, for example: Exists business like as bank that you neves uses  Local Storage and SessionStorage  and Variable you can use if extremely necessary

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @EvandroMendes